# Airflow Oracle Operator

Tags: oracle, airflow, operator-keyword

Am quite new to `Airflow` and I am trying to execute my first `DAG` using `Oracle` Operator. However, am getting error as

> "Invalid Syntax" as well as this "airflow.exceptions: dag_id could not be found. Either dag did not exist or failed to parse"

I had placed my `dag` at the same location where example_dags were present `(/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/example_dags/my_dag.py)` but somehow it is not showing in UI so I tried to execute by giving below command

```
airflow run example_sql_dag task_sql 2020-1-17
```

Below is the code of my oracle dag:

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.oracle_operator import OracleOperator

default_args = {
'owner': 'Airflow',
'depends_on_past': False,
'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2),
'start_date': datetime(2020,01,17),   
'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
'email_on_failure': False,
'email_on_retry': False,
'retries': 0,
'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}


with DAG('example_sql_dag',
     default_args=default_args,
     catchup=False,
     schedule_interval='*/10 * * * *'
     ) as dag:
opr_sql = OracleOperator(task_id='task_sql',
                                       oracle_conn_id='Oracle_schema'
                                       sql= 'insert into table1 (a,b,c)values (1,2,3)',
                                               autocommit ='True')
```

Edit: I tried to execute the Python file directly by going to the location where the file was kept and did this: ./my_dag.py

But still no luck. This time I got Command not found errors.Maybe something is wrong with the script.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a "," between the `oracle_conn_id` and `sql` argument in your DAG definition.
Try:

```
opr_sql = OracleOperator(
    task_id='task_sql',
    oracle_conn_id='Oracle_schema',
    sql= 'insert into table1 (a,b,c) values (1,2,3)',
    autocommit ='True')
```